# ZendFramework and PHP in Subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, include-path, subdirectory

Running an application using zendframework and php. 
Writing a small application in a subfolder and want to include the topmenu in the subfolder. 
Not sure how I can configure the application to include the php from the main folder. 
Included some of the code from the topmenu. 
Would I type everything with `../` such as `<?php if (Zend_Registry::get('../config')?`

```
<div id="topmenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
<?php if (Zend_Registry::get('config')->get('logo_image')):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/" class="navbar-brand image pull-left">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Risa Logo" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl().'images/'.Zend_Registry::get('config')->get('logo_image')?>">
            </a>
<?php else:?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/" class="navbar-brand pull-left">
                <span><?php echo Zend_Registry::get('config')->get('network_name');?></span>
            </a>
<?php endif;?>'
```

Comment: I think the best is to set your base working path to `../` and use Zend just like you used to before. Not sure if you get problems autoloading otherwise. Don't forget to bootstrap Zend Application.

Answer (score 0):

To do it right way you should add your menu using viewHelper. I can post more detail if you are interested to do it like this.